# Change URL using .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to change url for example
**http://localhost/mysite/index.php?page=about**
will become 
**http://localhost/mysite/index/about**

I also used `RewriteRule ^index/(.*) /index.php?page=$1` and if I type 
**http://localhost/mysite/index/about** in URL bar then it redirects to 
**http://localhost/xampp/splash.php**, the page which shows that XAMPP is working fine.

One think more mod_rewrite is also enabled.

and if I use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs 
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]
```

It shows the correct page but does not add style sheet and does not show images and also jQuery files.
And **Firebug** shows numbers of different errors eg:

1. $ is not defined
2. syntax error
3. jQuery is not defined
4. $("#slider-two").movingBoxes is not
   a function

any guide....?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enable in your server ? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the full path of the files you call for scripts, images and stylesheets like

```
<link type="text/stylesheet" src="http://www.example.com/styles/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/scripts/jquery-slider.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Coosal it's really works perfect but may you guide me if it negatively affect SEO or not?

Comment: Nope, it won't have negative effect to SEO. In fact, the url rewriting is SEO friendly. So you don't have to worry :)